# I rebased interactively on the master branch, so a feature branch now looks like it starts well before it did. How can I fix this?

Tags: git, branch, rebase, branching-and-merging

I had a master branch and a feature branch:

```
A --- B --- C --- D --- E Master
             \
              F - G --- H Feature
```

Then I rebased the master branch interactively, such that C changed (and become C'. Now the latest commit in common between the branches is B:

```
A --- B --- C' --- D --- E Master
       \
         C - F --- G --- H Feature
```

How I can get back to what I really *meant*? That is, where the feature branch only has the relevant commits in it, not the old ones which I have subtly changed:

```
A --- B --- C' --- D --- E Master
             \
               F - G --- H Feature
```

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy. Rebase your feature branch onto C':

```sh
git rebase --onto C' C Feature
```

The `C Feature` part selects the commits from `C` to `Feature (head)` (i.e. `F`, `G` and `H`), the `--onto C'` part rebases them onto `C'`.

You can add the interactive `-i` switch if you want to see what it will do before it does it.

Answer (score 1):

```
git checkout -B Master Master@{1}
```

to put the `Master` label back where it was before you moved it (say `git reflog Master` to see a list of where it's been), then do the rebase you really wanted.